# How do I iterate through a list of related objects in a django template?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to get related models printing in a view. I'm pretty sure the DB itself is set up properly, including keys and such, and there is data in the table to play with. What I'm not sure about is

- Am I wiring the models to the correct table and column names?
- Am I loading the phones for each voter?
- How do I iterate over the relationship itself?

I can get the voter information itself, but nothing I try with the related `Phone` model works.

Tables:

```
voters:
  id int primary key
  first_name varchar

phones:
  id int primary_key
  phone_number varchar

voter_phones:
  voter_id FK
  phone_id FK
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models


class Phone(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'phones'


class Voter(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phones = models.ManyToManyField('Phone', through='VoterPhone', related_name='voters', through_fields=('voter_id', 'phone_id'))

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'voters'


class VoterPhone(models.Model):
    voter = models.ForeignKey('Voter', related_name='voter_phones')
    phone = models.ForeignKey('Phone', related_name='voter_phones')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'voter_phones'
```

The view:

```
def results(request):
    voters = Voter.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'site/results.html', {'voters': voters})
```

The template:

```
{% for voter in voters %}
  {{ voter.first_name }}
  {% for phone in voter.phones_set.all %}
    {{ phone.phone_number }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The end result is a list of voter names, and no phone numbers. What am I missing?

EDIT: I created a local database, generated and ran django migrations, and inserted some dummy data. I still get no phone numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got something working. I had to make the following changes:

- got the tables renamed to their default django names (namely, voters_phones instead of voter_phones)
- found that the foreign keys in voters_phones were int(11) while the primary keys in both voters and phones were bigint(20)
- removed the join models

Thanks for your help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use Django to create database, you need to specify table name for the VoterPhone class. Django would not choose voterphones table as the intermediate table. I think by setting 
*class Meta:
        db_table = 'voterphones'* 
for VoterPhone class you should be able to see related phone numbers.

Comment: what syntax would I use in the template to iterate over those phones?

Comment: Your template looks fine, No need to change it.

Comment: I didn't copy and paste the meta block by accident, but it's there. I get an error from the template itself saying 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache' at the line in the template with for phone in voter.phones.all.

Comment: @whiterook6 I seem to recall a bug that caused that same error or a very similar one, but it was fixed later on. What Django version are you on?

Comment: @MNour `VoterPhone` is like any other model, in that it generates a table name from the app name and model name. Explicitly defining a table name certainly won't fix anything unless you need to connect to a legacy database that uses non-default table names.

Comment: @knbk whiterook6 uses voter_phones table to store VoterPhone objects. Django does not make this name for VoterPhone automatically, as I know it uses app name_classname or classname without any 's' at the end, therefore I thought that whiterook6 is using a legacy database. BTW, I changed my post to make it clear.

Comment: I've fixed my post. VoterPhone definitely has the meta block with a properly set db table. I don't have control over the DB schema so I can't just have Django make the tables for me with its preferred naming scheme

Comment: Either way it would not explain or fix the error. @whiterook6 Can you post the full traceback and your django version?

Comment: I'm not getting a traceback -- I'm simply getting a view with voter first names and no phones printed. My version is 1.9.7. I also changed the template to read `for phone in voter.phones_set.all` instead of voter.phones.all as that gave me an Attribute Error: ManyToManyField' object has no attribute '_m2m_reverse_name_cache'

Comment: @whiterook6 Which of the two works in your view code or in the shell, `voter.phones_set.all()` or `voter.phones.all()`? It seems odd that `voter.phones_set.all()` would give that specific error unless that's the actual name of the relation. Can you show the traceback related to that AttributeError?